# Is $\frac{2^{tK} -1}{K}$ increasing with $K$?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

How to prove that $$f = \frac{2^{tK} -1}{K}$$ is increasing with $K$, where $t > 0$ and $K = 1, 2, 3, \dotsc$? That is, I want to prove that the above expression is maximized as $K \to \infty$.

**My attempt**:

Relaxing $K > 0$ to be continuous, I tried showing that the derivative
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial K} = \frac{(\ln(2)tK-1)2^{tK}+1}{K^2} > 0.$$ This means that we have to show that:
$$(\ln(2)tK-1)2^{tK}+1 > 0.$$
But I have been unable to show this. What I tried further unsuccessfully is that, to show $(\ln(2)tK-1)2^{tK}+1 > 0$ as $t \to 0_{+}$, because if the inequality holds for $t \to 0_{+}$, it holds for any $t > 0$.

Comment: you can fix $t>0$. 
You are only interested in the case when $K$ is large, so for large enough $K$ you get $tK>x$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$.
Here $tK>1$ is sufficient, so it is pretty straight forward, since $\ln(2)tK$ is non decreasing as $K\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Be careful, saying that $f$ is increasing and that $f$ is maximized as $K \rightarrow \infty$ are different things. A function could decrease on some interval but eventually be increasing past some $x$ value. Think of $\vert x \vert$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s=tln(2)$.   Then $f=\frac{e^{sK}-1}{K}=\frac{1}{K}(\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(sK)^j}{j!})$  Each term in the sum increases with $s$.  Therefore $f$ increases with $t$ for each $K$.  Also for fixed $s$, each term from $j=2$ onward, after dividing by $K$, increases with $K$.